# Manage Data Permission for Shared Data Extensions

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

I'm setting up permissions for shared data extensions for business units in marketing cloud. I'd like to know the details for the "manage data" permission, as opposed to view/update/delete. I've tried several searches and I'm not seeing what specifically this permission allows in the docs. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are talking about Permissions for **Shared Data Extensions**.

What I thought is not included in View, Update or Delete is the editing / creation / deletion of Data Extension Fields. But that appears to be wrong.

I could not find any documentation either. So I just tested a few things.
What I found out was, that it is actually the other way around.

View, Update and Delete describe actions for the Data Extension itself, whereas "Manage Data" constrolls actions on a Record Level.

**Examples**:

- If you deny "Manage Data" the "Records"-Tab will not be available.
- If you deny "View" users will not see the Data Extension at all.
- If you deny "Delete" users will not be able to delete the Data Extension, but might be able to delete records if "Manage Data" is allowed.

Comment: Glad it's not just me who's finding big gaps in the documentation. This is exactly what I needed to know. I edited to clarfiy that my question refers to shared data extensions.